# "Columns" changes to "columns" resulting in compile error "Expected Function or variable"

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

When I write "**C**olumns.Count" and I go to the next line, it turns into "**c**olumns.count".

When I run my macro I get this error message:

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I keep the capital C?

Comment: Can you copy & paste something of your code?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work fine

Comment: You might have somewhere a variable called columns. Try change its name, and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The VBA editor will automatically adjust the case for defined variables.  So if you created a variable (i.e. `Dim columns`), the editor will auto-correct as you type any instance of the word "*columns*" to match the case in the Dim statement.  Conversely, changing the capitalization in the Dim statement will adjust all instances in the following code.

Also, *Columns* is a keyword for Excel, so I wouldn't recommend defining a variable of that name.  It could produce some issues.

Comment: I created a Sub procedure called Columns which I immediately deleted because it is a keyword for Excel, as you say, but ever since there seems to be no way back, even if the Sub has been deleted. Are the variables/subs/etc stored somewhere? That would explain why deleting the sub did not solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Deleting the Sub should have taken care of it.  Have you tried (if possible) creating a new Excel document and copying your code into it?  Or closing/re-opening Excel?

Comment: I can't... the file is way too large and has way too much content. I mean, it is plan B but I hope it doesn't come to that. Is there no way of making VBA forget that sub ever existed? Thanks

Comment: Great question.  I just duplicated what you're seeing.  It definitely appears to be a bug.  I found that if I close the Excel file, the VBA project remains open in the VBA editor (which shouldn't happen).  And re-opening the file causes an additional instance of the project to show up in the VBA editor.

Comment: I found that if i exported and then removed all VBA modules, saved the spreadsheet, closed/re-opened it, and then re-imported the modules, the problem could be resolved.  Hopefully you don't have too many modules or that may not be helpful.

Comment: It did not solve the issue, I don't know what it is. Luckily I had a backup version of the file from before I created the sub that ruined it all :) Thank you anyway!